# Start quartz trigger next day at specified time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

How can i pause my quartz trigger and start it next day at its specified start time ?
For eg. My cron expression is * 0/20 15-00 * * ? So when i pause my trigger it should start next day at 15:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, pausing a trigger does not affect its next fire time.

I.e. if you have a CronTrigger which runs every day at 6 o'clock, and you pausing that trigger before its firing for that day, it is not firing.

But since the next fire time is not changed, that trigger should immediatly fire or execute its [MisfireInstruction](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example5.html) after unpausing it again. Whether the trigger is fired or its MisfireInstruction is executed depends on the MisfireThreshold.

For the case of a CronTrigger you could just adapt the nextFireTime before unpausing the CronTrigger. ( see `CronTrigger.setNextFireTime()` )

Comment: How can i set the nextfiretime to next day's trigger start time?

Comment: I would recommend to do the following: Every time before you unpause a Trigger, you do `cronTrigger.setNextFireTime(cronTrigger.getFireTimeAfter

(new Date()))`. That just set the next fire time of the CronTrigger to the next valid time that matches the associated CronExpression after now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this and get back to you.